# Finding a group of vertices in a graph so that each vertex can reach k other vertices

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph-theory

Let G=(V,E) be a directed graph and k is an integer. I need to find in a linear time the group of vertices so that each vertex in this group can reach exactly k vertices (including itself).

The first thing I thought about was to use Kosaraju's algorithm in order to find the strongly connected components of the graph. Each vertex inside a connected component can obiously reach at least the vertices in this connected component, so all is left is to see how the components are connected. However, I did not come up with a linear solution.

Any hints?

Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you say what are the vertices and edges in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step is correct. Each strongly connected components can be substituted with one vertex, for which starting # of reachable vertices is number of elements in this component. After operation of substituting we get directed acyclic graph. Now for each of this super vertices we want to find how many vertices can be reached from it. One idea would be to sort this graph topologically. After this operation all arrows point into one direction. Without loss of generality we can assume they point to the right, so our graph looks more or less like this:

```
a -> b ----> e -> f -> g
  \             /
    -> c -> d -
```

For each vertex we have its starting counter which we got from first phase of assembling vertices from one strongly connected components. What we would like to do now is go from right to left and for each vertex have set of vertices reachable from it. Operation which we need is fast merge of this sets. Here with help comes Find-Union data structure. You can add one more field to usual `size` and `rank` which will store # of reachable vertices and update it as you `union` two sets.

This will lead to almost linear time: `O(n * alpha(n))` where `alpha(n)` is inverse of Ackermann function which is very very small. For huge data it will not be bigger than `5`, so you can think of it as constant.

I wonder if somebody can make it without `alpha`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first answer is incorrect. You might be able to create the reachable group of nodes for every node from a union of its sons' reachables in the scc graph BUT you need to make copies of the sons' groups in order to do this (or else you mess up their reachables). So the complexity is n*n minimum or in fact n * E if im not mistaking. Thats because the copies need to be made * before * the union operation, so you need to go through n*(num of sons) for each node..The complexity of this would be n*E + n(alpha(n)). Completely redundant therefore to use union find..You can use n sized arrays for each node.